# Unable to Retrieve HttpContext.Current.User in MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I have a basic MVC (.Net 4.5) app within which I am trying to get the user's information.

This line of code works in a separate webforms app, but I am having difficulty using it in this app.  Basically _user gets populated with the default values, there are no user specific values (for example name) which are getting populated.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IPrincipal _user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
        return View();
    }
```

Things I have tried:

- Added `<authentication mode="Windows" />` to web config
- Enabled windows authentication in project properties
- Disabled Anonymous Authentication in project properties  - This is not desirable because it forces a login window which is not the behavior I want.

Comment: This is just an educated guess, but are you missing something in your Startup.cs that the other project had?

Comment: How are you running this? If it isn't IIS, HttpContext.Current doesn't work.  If you are using IIS (and not IIS Express) those authentication settings need to be defined on IIS itself for this site or it won't push through.

Comment: @Louis - nothing that I can see

Comment: @Daniel - Locally through IIS, also deployed to an App Service in Azure.  Even if I had to configure something locally in IIS, surely that wouldn't effect what happens in Azure?  Although that's given me the idea to check the web app settings for the functioning app to see what is specified.

Comment: @user3626232 If this is Azure, then Windows Credentials aren't going to work...  Unless its with Azure AD?  Even still, I don't think it would work like that.

Comment: @Daniel You are correct, after a lot of digging around this project had code which is no longer being used, including the old windows authentication logic.  Thanks for the help.